# How can I convert a string to a list in a list? (Python)

Tags: python

I want to convert pieces of a string into lists and those lists into a matrix. For example:
My string is `"75 95 64 17 47 82 18 35 87 10 20 04 82 47 65 19 01 23 75 03 34 88 02 77 73 07 63 67 99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92 41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33 41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29 53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14 70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57 91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"`. I want `75`in a list1. `95, 64` in list2, `17, 47, 82` in list3 etc. Then I want to put those list in one (head) list/matrix. So it would be `[[75][95,64][17,47,82]]`. When I tried to do this the outcome was: `[['75']['95','64']['17','47','82']]`.

The code I wrote:

```
String = "75 95 64 17 47 82 18 35 87 10 20 04 82 47 65 19 01 23 75 03 34 88 02 77 73 07 63 67 99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92 41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33 41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29 53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14 70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57 91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"
lst1 = list(String.split(" "))
matrix = []
x = 0
while lst1 != []:
    matrix.append(lst1[:1+x])
    lst1 = lst1[1+x:]
    x += 1
print(matrix)
```

My question is: **What must I change in order to get the outcome that I want (so without ' ' in the matrix)?**

Comment: `lst1 = list(map(int, String.split(" ")))`

Comment: You've already done the hard part. To get `75` from `"75"` call `int()` on it.

Comment: Note that `04` can't be expressed without quotes, casting it to an int will produce only `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. The only thing that you missed, was the conversion of the string values (e.g. `'75'` to `75`).

In order to do this, you could write it like this:

```python
    while lst1 != []:
        converted_list = [ int(item) for item in lst1[:1+x] ]
        matrix.append(converted_list)
```

This will convert each item from the list into an int, storing it in a new list that you can append to your matrix, while still being able to perform other operations on your list in the same way as you would have done previously.

Answer (score -1):

I just added the code bellow after your code:

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        matrix[i][j] = int(matrix[i][j])
```

I'm looking for a more pythonic way to doing this :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).